# How to change icon when the state changes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, icons, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to change an icon of the button renderized by the Flatlist when the state changes and in sequence store this data. I created a prop true to represent an icon name and another false to represent another icon name to can see the state changes, but the icon not is recognized. Someone can help me?

Obs: I'm using react-native-paper to style my app.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet,ScrollView, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { Button, Title, Badge } from 'react-native-paper';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'


const App = () => {

    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    const [iconSave, setIconSave] = useState(false)


    function favRecipe(id){
        const favorites = recipes.map( recipe => {
            return recipe.id === id? {...recipe, marked:!recipe.marked} : recipe
        })
        setRecipes(favorites)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const favoritedTotal = recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.marked)
        const favIcons = recipes.filter(icon => icon == true? 'star' : 'book')
        setCount(favoritedTotal.length)
        setIconSave(favIcons)
    }, [recipes])



    useEffect(() => {

        const dataRecipes = [
            {id: 1, recipe: 'Fricassê', icon: true},
            {id: 2, recipe: 'Frango assado', icon: true},
            {id: 3, recipe: 'Feijoada', icon: true},
            {id: 4, recipe: 'Feijão tropeiro', icon: true},
            {id: 5, recipe: 'Bolo de chocolate', icon: true},
            {id: 6, recipe: 'Cookies', icon: true},
            {id: 7, recipe: 'Sorvete caseiro', icon: true},
            {id: 8, recipe: 'Torta tradicional', icon: true},
            {id: 9, recipe: 'Sanduíche', icon: true},
            {id: 10, recipe: 'Torta de frango', icon: true},
            {id: 11, recipe: 'Pão de queijo', icon: true},
            {id: 12, recipe: 'Pastel português', icon: true}
        ]
        setRecipes(dataRecipes)

    }, [])

    const storeData = async () => {
        try{
            await 
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@store_icons', JSON.stringify(iconSave)),
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@store_count', JSON.stringify(count)),
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@store_recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes)).then(Alert.alert('Alerta', 'Receitas salvas com sucesso.'))
        }catch(e){
            Alert.alert('Algo deu errado, tente novamente.')
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        AsyncStorage.getItem('@store_count').then(value => setCount(value))
    }, [])

    useEffect(()=> {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('@store_icons').then(value => setIconSave(value))
    }, [])


    return (
        <ScrollView style={{padding:10, marginBottom: 10}}>
        <Badge>{count}</Badge>
            <Title style={{padding: 10}}>Receitas favoritas:</Title>
            <FlatList
            data={recipes}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View style={styles.containerList}>
                <Button icon={iconSave} mode='outlined' onPress={() => favRecipe(item.id)}>{item.recipe}</Button>
                </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
            <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Button mode='contained' onPress={storeData} style={{marginBottom: 20, margin: 5}}>Salvar informações</Button>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerList:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        padding: 10
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Flatlist's code to below:

```
           <FlatList
            data={recipes}
            extraData={iconSave}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View style={styles.containerList}>
                <Button icon={iconSave} mode='outlined' onPress={() => favRecipe(item.id)}>{item.recipe}</Button>
                </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
```

Here I added extraData prop to flatlist, so it will re-render when the extra Data changes.
Reference : https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata